# Why is this query returning ""

Tags: php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";

$connection = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if (!$connection){
    die("Connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
}

$connected_db = mysql_select_db('users', $connection);
if (!$connected_db){
    die('Can\'t use user database: ' . mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pw FROM login WHERE name=\"" . $_POST['username'] . "\"");
```

The login table is as follows:

```
id int(4)
name char(16)
pw char(64)
```

obviously `^` is not a query, just a summary of what the table is comprised of
The query towards the end `($result = mysql_query("SELECT pw FROM login WHERE name...")` finds usernames just fine, and the passwords are hashed using `password_hash(password, DEFAULT_PASSWORD)` and stored in the database. but `$result['pw']` is returning an empty string. why? I'm trying to retrieve the stored hash from the database for a login, to compare with password_verify using a login form's POST data. The query `SELECT pw FROM login WHERE name=testuser;` works just fine in `phpmyadmin`

Comment: sql likes values t obe in single quotes, try $result = mysql_query("SELECT pw FROM login WHERE name='" . $_POST['username'] . "'");

Answer (score 0):

First, while in developing mode, add this at the top of you php script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

This above will allow you to check for errors on you script.

In regards to your code, you're vulnerable to [mysql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)
To avoid that use the `php` [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function.
Also, your double quotes are misplaced.
Your code may look like this:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pw FROM login WHERE name='$username'");
```

Comment: thank you, i'm aware of the injection vulnerability. this is a small personal project for my fiance, so injections aren't a big deal right now, though i'm aware of the danger of injections.